# SceneKit Audio - How to add a SCNPlayer to a SCNNode and just play back a sound

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, audio, scenekit

I'm currently using this code (inside a SCNNode subclass) to play back a sound in SceneKit.

```
    let audioSource = SCNAudioSource(named: "coin.wav")
    let audioPlayer = SCNAudioPlayer(source: audioSource)
    self.addAudioPlayer(audioPlayer)
```

This is not ideal as it fills the audioPlayers array everytime I play a new sound. Ideally, I could have one SCNAudioPlayer for each sound that I want to play and just call a "play" function to play it back.

Unfortunately, I could not find a play function. 
What also irritates me, is that SCNAudioPlayer automatically plays the sound when added to a node. But I want to set up my whole scene without any sounds playing back and then at a later point of time, play the sounds.

What is the correct way of using SceneKit's Audio Engine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For playing a single sound as/if when hit or otherwise instigated by an event and/or input...

There's a special "action": SCNAction.playAudioSource

```
class func playAudioSource(_ source: SCNAudioSource,
     waitForCompletion wait: Bool) -> SCNAction
```

Then, to play the sound, run it on a node:

```
myNode.runAction(myActionName)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the action as was previously answered, as it is syntactically simpler to use.

SCNAudioPlayers are recycled by the engine so you do not need to be concerned about their lifespan unless you need to modify them while they're playing.
The idea behind the SceneKit audio engine is that sounds should behave in the same way that SCNNodes do. If a node is in the scene graph then it is visible and so are its geometry, particle systems, etc. So if a sound is attached to a node it should start playing right away if the node is visible (and stop if it is hidden).

The audio source only represents the actual audio data. Think of it as of a texture: it is loaded once and can be referenced by a number of materials on a number of 3d nodes.
The audio player instantiates the audio source so that you can play it on multiple nodes at the same time, just like you would use the same material for different geometries on different nodes.

Hope this helps and give some perspective on the design choices,

S.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth reply!

Comment: Sideways question: anyway to use FMOD or similar as an AudioSource/Player so as to gain things like, time stretch, delay, chorus etc?

Comment: You can use you own engine by creating SCNAudioPlayers that uses a custom AVAudioNode object but I don't know if FMOD provides this kind of interoperability. Alternatively you can have a look at the other services AVAudioNode provides as I believe it can be integrated with audio units that do provide Chorus, Flanger, etc.